# Writing file changes file permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, amazon-web-services, permissions, sidekiq

Hello everybody and sorry in advance for my english!

I have a rails app running on a linux AWS EC2 instance.
My app writes in a file which is located in the app directory (var/app/etcetc...).

I also have tasks which are launched with sidekiq (user executing the daemon is ec2-user). One of this task has to access this file (read and probably execute).

Problem is that when the web app writes in the file, permissions on that file are set as follow: rw-rw---- and the owner of this file is webapp (from the webapp group).

When permissions are like that, my task crash with a permission denied when trying to access the file.

I tried to add ec2-user (who runs the sidekiq task) to the webapp group but it still crash.

Does someone has an idea of how can I solve this issue?

What can I do to force linux to set the right permissions after the file is modified by the wep app?
I know that I can execute FileUtils.chmod_R 0777 'filename' (rails command) after my app writes in the file but it's crappy.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the code you use to open the file for writing?

Comment: The file in question is a Ferret index file  so to open it I use `Ferret::Index::Index.new(path: "path_to_file", create: false)`